# Vectorization for array multiplication

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have an 3d array U, and a 2d matrix A. I want to do the multiplication like following way. How can I vectorize my code? The loop is too slow, of course.

```
for j=1:N
 for k=1:N
 UU(:,j,k)=A*U(:,j,k);
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape `U` to `2D` and perform the matrix-multiplication, thus reducing the first axis/dimension of `U` with `A`'s last axis to give us a 2D array. Finally, reshape back to `3D` for the final result, like so -

```
[m1,n1] = size(A);
[~,m2,n2] = size(U);
out = reshape(A*reshape(U,[n1,m2*n2]),[m1,m2,n2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your matrices, you might find that eliminating both loops chews up a lot of memory, and that removing just the loop over the columns is sufficient,

```
for k = 1:N
   UU(:,:,k) = A*U(:,:,k);
end
```